# Giving a TextBox two validation rules based on a boolean binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I currently have a `TextBox` that has a validation rule `ModelPathWithFolderRule`.

```
<TextBox Name="ModelNameBox"
                       Grid.Row="2"
                       Grid.Column="0"
                       Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
  <TextBox.Text>
    <Binding Path="ModelUploadName" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
      <Binding.ValidationRules>
        <validationRules:ModelPathWithFolderRule />
      </Binding.ValidationRules>
    </Binding>
  </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

I would like to replace the validation rule with `LimitedUserUploadPathRule` when the boolean property `IsLimitedUserGroup` is `true`.

I attempted to work around this by simply creating two text boxes with the different rules and alternating their visibility. However, this did not work, as the `Name` of the text box cannot be used twice and the name is used to generate error messages, so I would like to keep it the same for both text boxes.

How else can I go about doing this? I would like to stick using `ValidationRules`, and keep it within the Xaml code itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this in XAML, you could create a style that switches bindings for `Text` depending on your `IsLimitedUserGroup` property. This way, you can specify different validation rules.

```
<Style x:Key="MyTextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
   <Setter Property="Text">
      <Setter.Value>
         <Binding Path="ModelUploadName" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
               <local:ModelPathWithFolderRule />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
         </Binding>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
   <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsLimitedUserGroup}" Value="True">
         <Setter Property="Text">
            <Setter.Value>
               <Binding Path="ModelUploadName" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                  <Binding.ValidationRules>
                     <local:LimitedUserUploadPathRule />
                  </Binding.ValidationRules>
               </Binding>
            </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
      </DataTrigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Assign the style to your `TextBox` and you can still use it as before.

```
<TextBox Name="ModelNameBox"
         Style="{StaticResource MyTextBoxStyle}"
         Grid.Row="2"
         Grid.Column="0"
         Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
```